# How can I make my custom app list show up properly in MDT 2012

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, mdt-2012, mdt

I have an MDT task sequence that installs an OS and presents an application list based on your OU choice (differing departments need separate applications).  When booting to WinPE and running the task sequence the selection options show properly and install fine.

However, when running the task sequence as a refresh from Windows, the application only shows the default panel with the sample application.  According to the logs, it is accessing and running the right file (plus if it couldn't find the file, it would error out the task sequence) but not displaying properly.

Logs for the launch of this wizard are copied below:

```
Expand a string: WinPEandFullOS TSManager 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 17324 (0x43AC)
Executing command line: smsswd.exe /run: cscript.exe "%DeployRoot%\Scripts\UDIWizard.wsf" /definition:"AppLists\%OSDInstallOU%.xml" TSManager 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 17324 (0x43AC)
[ smsswd.exe ] InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
PackageID = '' InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
BaseVar = '', ContinueOnError='' InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
ProgramName = 'cscript.exe "C:\_SMSTaskSequence\WDPackage\Scripts\UDIWizard.wsf" /definition:"AppLists\OSA.xml"' InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
SwdAction = '0001' InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Working dir 'C:\_SMSTaskSequence\WDPackage\Tools\X64' InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Executing command line: Run command line InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8 InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Property definition is now = AppLists\OSA.xml InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 6.1.2373.0 InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
The task sequencer log is located at C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\SMSTS.LOG.  For task sequence failures, please consult this log. InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Using tsprogressui.exe for displaying wizard UI InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Working directory: C:\_SMSTaskSequence\WDPackage\Tools\x64 InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Saving edited configuration file as C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\OSDSetupWizard.xml InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Copying app file C:\_SMSTaskSequence\WDPackage\Scripts\AppLists\OSA.xml.app to C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\OSDSetupWizard.xml.app InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
Selected wizard stage option: REFRESH InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
About to run command: ServiceUI.exe -process:tsprogressui.exe OSDSetupWizard.exe /xml:"C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\SMSTSLog\OSDSetupWizard.xml" /stage:REFRESH InstallSoftware 8/23/2013 9:08:09 AM 12564 (0x3114)
```

I could use some pointers on what is going wrong.

Comment: Still having this issue occur, does anyone have any possible resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a refresh, in order to get the application list to show up on a second wizard, you must run the Application Discovery scan during the second wizard.  It reads in the .xml.app file and populates the list.